# Minecraft item blacklist

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to compare the items in a chest-minecart with a blacklist.
I'm currently using `/execute positioned -23 110 -274 as @e[type=minecraft:chest_minecart,distance=..1] unless data entity @s {Items:[{id:"minecraft:tnt"}]} unless data entity @s {Items:[{id:"minecraft:iron_sword"}]}`, but is there a way to use something like a chest as a blacklist and compare like these two inventories. It should check, if one of the chest-items is in the minecart`s inventory.